# Is Criteria in Spring Data Mongo db injection safe?

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to expose an api that allows ability to query another component's data which is in mongodb. In line with this, that api will have a parameters containing field names and values.

How do I prevent NoSQL injections for the ff:

```
   Criteria.where(dbFieldName).is(name);
   dynamicQuery.addCriteria(nameCriteria);
```